# Psycopg2 error at or near %

Tags: postgresql, python

[image]

Note location of cursor. At first I thought it was the lack of a semi colon, but as you can see, putting one in does not solve the problem or change the error. I compared this code to samples I found on http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html :

[image]

Based on this, I don't see the problem. FWIW, Pylint in ST3 has no issues with this code. thanks.

```
from os import getcwd, listdir
import psycopg2
from io import open

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=ktab user=malikarumi")
cur = conn.cursor()
path = getcwd()
filenames = listdir(path)

for filename in filenames:
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    f1 = f.read()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO testable (title, content, chron_date, clock)\
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"),
    (filename, f1, '2017-12-30', '23:59:00'),

conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: How can we possibly assist you with out the code around? `ktab_odt4.py` line 21

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I can't seem to find the sweet spot on this issue. I get criticized for not putting enough. I put more, I get criticized for putting too much, I cut back, and on and on it goes.....

Comment: Don't you have a parenthesis mismatch in your python code there?..

Comment: Or .. more correctly...  Not mismatched, but misplaced parenthesis.

Comment: @JoishiBodio: Yes, it seems you are right. This is why I need another pair of eyes. The code ran, I was returned to the prompt with no further errors, but I got ZERO in the table! sigh..... I guess that should be a different issue and a different post with a different question. But thanks!  Did you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced parenthesis.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    f1 = f.read()
    cur.execute(
        "INSERT INTO testable (title, content, chron_date, clock) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);", # remove parenthesis here, which ends the execute call
        (filename, f1, '2017-12-30', '23:59:00')
    ) # move above parenthesis here
```